# changing the background url of div with the value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

Hi everyone sorry for the question but I have been changing url's, ""(those things), ''( and those) for the past hour.

I am trying to change the background url of a div. I know this has been asked before, but there where no answers there about using an array with links to the images. Instead the person put the links in the brackets of the function which I think is pretty nasty code.

this is what I am trying:

**HTML**

```
<div id="display"></div>
<a href="#" onClick="changeimg(0, event)"><img alt="img" src="img/option/img1"></a>
<a href="#" onClick="changeimg(1, event)"><img alt="img" src="img/option/img2"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#display{
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:url(../img/img1.JPG);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**JS**

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');

var imgs = [
    'img/img1.JPG',
    'img/img2.JPG'
];

function changeimg(x, e) {
    var i = x;

    display.style.backgroundImage = "url(imgs[i])";
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

when I do this I get an ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND message in the console.
when I copy one of the links of the array in the url like:

```
display.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/img2.JPG)";
```

it changes the image to the one linked. So how do I make the index work?

(note that i am using separate images for display in the 'display' and for the options. I did this so the website doesnt have to load 20 huge images but 1)

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using ES6 Template literals. For your problem, replace your code with the below one.

`display.style.backgroundImage =`url(${imgs[i]})`;`

Comment: I get a syntax error cause it expected an ) and got a {?

Comment: OMG I added the `` things and it WORKS!! you are a hero, cause I never would of thought of this

Comment: Thanks, I enjoy helping when I am able to

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');

var imgs = [
    'img/img1.JPG',
    'img/img2.JPG'
];

function changeimg(x, e) {
    var i = x;

    display.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ imgs[i] + "')"
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Hope this helps!